# Carrierwave: How to validate that image is attached? (either upload, or remote_url)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to make sure that every instance of Picture model has a file attached.

In other words - there are two fields in the form:

```
:file
:remote_file_url
```

I want user to fill in at least one of them.

When I validate presence of :file, and submit remote_file_url instead of file - then it gives validation error.

The only way I found for now is do smth like this:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :file_xor_remote_file_url

  private    
  def file_xor_remote_file_url
    if !(file.blank? ^ remote_file_url.blank?)
      errors.add(:base, "Specify a file to upload, or file URL, not both")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: `if file.blank? && remote_file_url.blank?` might be more idiomatic ruby, but what is your question overall?

Comment: `validates_presence_of :file` worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The wiki](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Validate-uploads-with-Active-Record) says you can validate your upload like this:

```
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
validates_presence_of :avatar
```

It doesn't mention any different handling for remote URLs, but underlines that Carrierwave validates the *presence of the file* rather than just the presence of an URL. So a given remote URL must refer to a valid file that can be uploaded.

You said that "validate presence of :file", but perhaps this could be the point. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is it. Remember to use `validates` for Rails 4